# Best way to implement HTML5 live streaming video on Android 3+

Tags: android, html5-video, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I have Wowza for streaming live TV channels. I tried to use HTTP live streaming (HLS) but Chrome play only audio (issue [17118](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17118)), embeded Android browser start playing video, but very unstable (often crashes). Tested on Galaxy Nexus (JB) and Nexus 7.
Even on Google TV (Sony NSZ-GS7) playback is not stable, play only first 5-10 minutes in Chrome and then stops.

In the same time on iOS (iPad 2) playback is completely stable.

As i understand - now Flash is not an option for Android.

So is it possible to get working live streaming video (live tv channel) in browser on Android 3+?

```
<video controls src="http://example.com:1935/live/ch1.stream/playlist.m3u8">
</video>
```

Comment: I believe ICS and beyond has HLS support. There is a hls player out there in the market for ICS. Check that. It should play your video fine.

Comment: @user1559108 yes, for example MX Player play my video, but i need embedded video in html (video-tag).

Comment: You can use video tag and give the m3u8 file. However not all phones play it correctly.  The solution is to have a mp4 file and use that.

Comment: @user1559108 there is no files, this is live tv channel streaming. m3u8 link in video tag unfortunately is very buggy.

Comment: Well then you have to move to RTSP. That is stable.

Comment: i replace src in video-tag to RTSP from Wowza - player is disabled and seems like even not tried to play this url.VLC successfully play this RTSP url.

Comment: Oh you can simple do <a href=rtsp://...> to the rtsp url. RTSP is not for html5 video tag.

Comment: @user1559108 of course this sould work, but i need embedded in HTML player which i can control from javascript.

Comment: @azhurb The answer is probably something like, "wait until Android 8.0" or whenever Google decides to stop screwing up HLS with every other release.